# Pygame blit image and text simultaneously

Tags: python, pygame

I'm new to pygame and now wanted to blit a background image with a text on top of it. Both together should appear on the screen for only half a second, then both should be gone again. The background image is meant to be full-screen.

*What I'm stuck on now*: every time, a black screen appears shortly before text and image are visible, they disappear quickly again.

```
    pg.init()
    info = pg.display.Info()
    window = pg.display.set_mode((info.current_w, info.current_h), pg.FULLSCREEN)
    
    font = pg.font.SysFont("Arial", 33, bold=True)
    text = font.render(text, True, (0, 0, 0))
    background = pg.image.load('temp.png')
    
    window.blit(background, [0, 0])
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center = window.get_rect().center))
    pg.display.flip()
    sleep(0.5)
    pg.quit()
```

I feel like this has to be possibly quite easily, still I haven't found out how to do it just yet.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using the `time.sleep` function in your code. This function isn't good for GUIs since it delays the program for a given amount of time without checking for events and updating the display. This is why a black screen appears. So to fix your issue, I wrote a function called `wait` that waits a given amount of time without freezing the game.

## The `wait` Function:

```
def wait(ms):
    start = pg.time.get_ticks()

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit(0)

        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - start == ms:
            running = False

        blit_background()
```

## Explanation

It takes one parameter: `ms`, which is the amount of time that you want the program to wait in milliseconds (1 second = 1000 milliseconds). In the function, I set a variable called start to `pygame.time.get_ticks()`, which returns the current time. Then, inside a while loop, I created an event loop which checks for the `pygame.QUIT` event so that if the user tries to close the game while the function is still running, the game will respond and quit the program. After the event loop, I set a variable called now to `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get the current time. Then I checked if now (the current time) subtracted by start (the start time) is equal to `ms` (the given amount of waiting time in milliseconds). This checks if the given amount of time has passed. If it has, the while loop ends. If not, the while loop keeps running until that condition is True.

I also wrote another function called `blit_background`, which displays the background and the text on the screen. I am calling this function inside the `wait` function so that the screen can display the background and the text while also waiting for the given amount of time to pass.

## The `blit_background` Function:

```
def blit_background():
    window.blit(background, [0, 0])
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center=window.get_rect().center))
    pg.display.flip()
```

## Full Modified Code:

```
import pygame as pg
import pygame.time
import sys

pg.init()
info = pg.display.Info()
WIDTH = info.current_w
HEIGHT = info.current_h
window = pg.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT), pg.FULLSCREEN)

font = pg.font.SysFont("Arial", 33, bold=True)
text = font.render("text", True, (0, 0, 0))
background = pg.image.load('temp.png')
background = pg.transform.scale(background, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))


def blit_background():
    window.blit(background, [0, 0])
    window.blit(text, text.get_rect(center=window.get_rect().center))
    pg.display.flip()


def wait(ms):
    start = pg.time.get_ticks()

    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit(0)

        now = pg.time.get_ticks()
        if now - start == ms:
            running = False

        blit_background()

wait(500)
pg.quit()
sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I used the time.sleep function after pygame.display.flip, so I thought it would first update the screen and show both background and text and THEN wait. It seems that this is actually not the case?

Comment: Unfortunately, I still get the black screen for a very short time and right after that the intended background + text. But I can't really see why this is the case. @Roni

Comment: @kbr, oh I see. It’s because when you create a Pygame window, the background is set to black by default. So when you start drawing things on the window, the background of the window is black for less than a second and then the drawings appear. I think it just takes time for the drawings to load, and I don’t think there’s a way to prevent this delay. If this is your issue, then I think I should delete my answer since it doesn’t give a solution to that issue.

Comment: yes this was actually my issue. I think your answer and comment could still be helpful to others though!